# How to split a list of list by numbers?

Tags: python, regex, list

```
my_list = ['Rob Kardashian 00052369 1987-03-17 Reality Star',
'Brooke Barry 00213658 2001-03-30 TikTok Star',
'Bae De Leon 00896351 1997-08-02 Volleyball Player',
'Jonas Blue 02369785 1990-08-02 Music Producer']
```

I have a list of people names, IDs, DOBs, and Occupations. I want to split each person by names, ID, DOB, and their occupations.

I tried some stupid approach and but can only do part of the work, and I was wondering are there any better solutions?

Below is my code:

```
import re 

def remove(my_list): 
    pattern = '[0-9]'
    my_list = [re.sub(pattern, '', i) for i in my_list] 
    return my_list

print(remove(my_list))
```

But numbers are gone `['Rob Kardashian  -- Reality Star', 'Brooke Barry  -- TikTok Star', 'Bae De Leon  -- Volleyball Player', 'Jonas Blue  -- Music Producer']`

Then, I removed the ' -- '

```
[s.replace(' -- ',' ') for s in remove(my_list)]

['Rob Kardashian  Reality Star','Brooke Barry  TikTok Star','Bae De Leon  Volleyball Player','Jonas Blue  Music Producer']
```

My expected outputs would be a dataframe:

[image]

```
pd.DataFrame(my_list)
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I would consider a more explicit regex to actually match each field using named groups: https://regex101.com/r/rV7Azs/2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `re.split`:

```
import re
my_list = ['Rob Kardashian 00052369 1987-03-17 Reality Star', 'Brooke Barry 00213658 2001-03-30 TikTok Star', 'Bae De Leon 00896351 1997-08-02 Volleyball Player','Jonas Blue 02369785 1990-08-02 Music Producer']
new_l = [re.split('\s(?=\d)|(?<=\d)\s', i) for i in my_list]
```

Output:

```
[['Rob Kardashian', '00052369', '1987-03-17', 'Reality Star'], 
 ['Brooke Barry', '00213658', '2001-03-30', 'TikTok Star'], 
 ['Bae De Leon', '00896351', '1997-08-02', 'Volleyball Player'], 
 ['Jonas Blue', '02369785', '1990-08-02', 'Music Producer']]
```

Regex explanation:

`\s(?=\d)`: matches any instance of a space followed by a digit.

`|` (alternation):attempts to match every expression to its left, or every expression to its right, stopping once it finds a valid match.

`(?<=\d)\s`: matches any instance of a space proceeded by a digit.

Comment: Can I know what does it mean '\s(?=\d)|(?<=\d)\s'?

Comment: Maybe you would also like to take a look at http://regex101.com to quickly build the regex that fit your needs...

Comment: Thank you both! @Ajax1234@Ouss

Comment: @Jancos Glad to help!